# $\mathrm{Ext}^n(\mathcal F, i_*\mathcal G) =\mathrm{Ext}^n(i^*\mathcal F,\mathcal G)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a closed immersion $i: Z \hookrightarrow X$ a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ and a coherent sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Z$, do we have $\mathrm{Ext}^n(\mathcal{F}, i_*\mathcal{G}) = \mathrm{Ext}^n(i^*\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$? For $n = 0$ it is the usual adjunction, so can we deduce it by the usual "universal $\delta$-functor" argument?

Consider the exact $\delta$-functors $\mathrm{Coh}(Z) \to (Ab), \mathcal{G} \mapsto \mathrm{Ext}^n(\mathcal{F}, i_*\mathcal{G})$ and $\mathcal{G} \mapsto \mathrm{Ext}^n(i^*\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ (exact since $i_*$ is exact). They coincide for $n = 0$, so we just have to check if they are both effacable to coincide for every $n$.

Could we also derive this using derived categories?

Edit: It seems to be wrong: Take $i$ the inclusion of a closed point, then the RHS is always trivial, but I don't think the LHS is. E.g. $\mathrm{Ext}^1(k(x),k(x)) = T_x$ the Zariski tangent space. So where does the above "argument" go wrong?

Comment: It would be best if you wrote down in the question the argument in detail that you are thinking of, and *then* we can answer something useful. Otherwise, the answer is *yes for sufficiently general meanings of the word "usual"* and this does not help you or anyone!

Comment: (It is usually best if titles are not entirely composed of TeX formulas, by the way)

Comment: I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I feel somewhat weird answering your question almost a year later, but here it goes:

I've edited this a bunch of times, and I think the issue is that the left functor, $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathscr{F},i_*(-))$ is not effaceable and not universal. $i_*$ doesn't necessarily preserve injectives, in fact it preserves injectives iff $i^*$ is exact,(If $(\mathscr{F,G})$ is an adjoint pair of additive functors, then $\mathscr{G}$ preserves injectives if and only if $\mathscr{F}$ is exact, the 'only if' when we have enough injectives. See Weibel, *An introduction to homological algebra*, Proposition 2.3.10 for proof of the 'if' case, and the comment by t.b. below for the 'only if' case).

Comment: Left adjoints are right exact, so if $F$ is not exact then it must fail to be left exact. So there is a monomorphism that is sent to a non-monomorphism $F(m)\colon F(A) \to F(B)$ under $F$. *If there are enough injectives* then a morphism is monic if and only if all embeddings of the domain into an injective lift over it, so there is $F(A) \rightarrowtail I$ with $I$ injective such that $F(m)$ doesn't lift. By adjointness $G(I)$ cannot lift over $m$, so $G(I)$ isn't injective. The other direction is proved in Weibel, somewhere in chapter II, I think.

Comment: Thank you, I proved the other direction on my own, but I just found it in Weibel, I'll edit my post accordingly.